# bootstrap formvalidation.io remote validator with custom server side returned error message

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, validation, formvalidation-plugin

I am using the bootstrap formvalidation.io remote validator here:

http://formvalidation.io/validators/remote/

Is there any way I can get the error message from the server side to be shown on the client side when a validation error occurs.

Here is the json I return from the server side once an error occurs:

```
{
   "valid":false,
   "errorMessage":"The format for this postal code has to be in the format of 5 digits"
}
```

Comment: the json that you have returned returns after form submit ?

Comment: I am doing the validation when the submit button is being pressed - so an ajax validation will be happening before the actual http form post happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use additional data returned by the remote validator as described here: http://formvalidation.io/examples/using-data-returned-validator/

When the `onError` event is triggered, `data.result` contains your webservice's JSON response, so `data.result.errorMessage` is your message.

To set a different validator message, use the `updateMessage()` function described here: http://formvalidation.io/api/#update-message

Combined, your code should look something like this:

```
$("#form")
  .formValidation({
  // other validator options...
  fields: {
    field-x: {
      validators: {
        remote: { 
          // other remote validator options here 
          onError: function(e, data) {                
            $("#form").formValidation("updateMessage", "field-x", "remote", "Error: " + data.result.errorMessage);
          }          
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```